# Can Delegates.observable() be serializable?

Tags: kotlin

Given a class

```
class Pizza(name: String?) : Serializable {
    var name: String? by Delegates.observable(name, {_,_,_ -> })
}
```

Why is this not serializable? It crashes with

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.xxx.xxx.Pizza$$special$$inlined$observable$1
```

Comment: I can't compile your code, `Serializable` is `internal`, and `Delegates.observable` takes 2 parameters.

Comment: Sorry, it was an extract of a piece of code, I'll add the second parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The reason behind your issue is the delegates are stored as an array in a synthetic backing field which is neither marked as transient nor serialziable, so it prevents the serialization. However just marking the property with @Transient will probably ruin your serialized form. <sub>And may not work at all</sub>

Before JetBrains decide to make a final resolution to this issue, you should use `writeReplace` and `readResolve` to override the default serializing mechanism. I've provided a sample solution below:

```
class Pizza(name: String?) : Serializable {
    @Transient var name: String? by Delegates.observable(name)
    private fun writeReplace(stream: ObjectOutputStream): Object = SerialProxy(name)
    private class SerialProxy(var name: String): Serializable {
        private fun readResolve(): Object = Pizza(name)
    }
}
```

<sub>readObject()/writeObject() doesn't work because you have no way to set the delegate after constructor is invoked without using reflection.</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer is spot-on. I have a problem with this though, which is that I also need to know the initial value, which I use in the observable's callback. I guess that using writeReplace/readResolve I'd have to pass the initial value too? That would be a lot of boilerplate unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, the SerialProxy will have to include that property too, because java serialization doesn't know about the initial state of your object.